# Sending files in a formData through axios to a server reads undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

``
Searching how to send a file from a client using a input type=file to a API I found that I should be using a formData. I've done that according to some examples I saw but when I try to see what I sended on the server side it is just undefined.

This is the code on the cliente side:

```
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState(null);
    const files = fileList ? [...fileList] : [];    

    const handleUploadClick = () => {
        if (!fileList) {
            return;
        }

        // Create new FormData object and append files
        const data = new FormData();
        console.log(files[0], files[0].name)
        data.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);

        /*
        files.forEach((file, i) => {
            data.append('file', file, file.name);
        });
        */
        
        for (var pair of data.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
        }

        axios.post('/api/uploadPostFiles', data, {})
            .then( res => {
                console.log(res.statusText)
            })

        alert("File uploaded!")
    };
```

And this is the code on my server side:

```
 app.post("/api/uploadPostFiles", (req, res) => {
  let uploadFile = req.files.file
  const fileName = req.files.file.name
  console.log(fileName)  
  console.log(uploadFile)
  /*other things below but first I need to know I have the correct values*/
```

The error I receive is:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')`

PD: according to my research i don't have to use content-type = multipart/form-data in the post

I tried playing around with the req, tried req.files, req.file, req.body, but i can't find a way to get the file values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side:

```
axios.post("/api/uploadPostFiles", 
      {
        image:files[0]
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
      ).then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

For the back end you need a middleware for handling multipart/form-data.
I use multer.
To install multer:

```
npm install --save multer
```

Backend:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
        //destination of ur files
        cb(null,"./images")
    },
    filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
        //name of the file. you can name it what ever u want 
        cb(null,file.originalname);
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage:storageEngine});
/*the middleware argument is the property name of the image sent in the 
body. in our case its image */
app.post("/api/uploadPostFiles",upload.single("image"),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send("Image downloaded succesfuly!");
});
```

sorry if i make some expalanation mistakes my english is bad, i hope i answered your question.